# ¿Cómo hacer un Timeout simple en java?

Tags: java

Tengo que hacer Timeout Simple, que si en x cantidad de tiempo esa Api no me responde, tengo que dar la transacción como CANCELADA.

Con esta edicion que hice, me asemejo a lo que querría, pero aca a los 10s me imprime los 'Test'. yo necesito que si en eso 10s no me respondió la api, doy como cancelada la opereación

```
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<TransaccionDTO> iniciarTransaccion() throws Exception {
   ResponseEntity<TransaccionDTO> response = null;
    try {

        String s = (String) CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {

            System.out.println("test");
            System.out.println("test");
            System.out.println("test");
            System.out.println("test");
            System.out.println("test");

            return null;
        }).get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (TimeoutException | ExecutionException e) {
        System.out.println("Time out has occurred");
    } catch (InterruptedException | CommandLine.ExecutionException e) {
    }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     response = transaccionService.iniciarTransaccion();
    TransaccionDTO transaccion = new TransaccionDTO();
    return new ResponseEntity<TransaccionDTO>(transaccion, HttpStatus.valueOf(200));
}
```

Comment: Para empezar, si ejecutas una función que no retorna y quieres poder tener algún control, esa llamada la tendrás que lanzar en otro thread. Ese código que has escrito no tiene sentido porque todo lo que hay debajo del return no se ejecutará nunca.

Comment: Normalmente el límite de tiempo se establece desde la petición misma.

Comment: si no les molesta , podria darme algun ejemplo de como hacerlo?

Comment: Solo un Timeout no creo que sirva para lo que requieres, como realizas la petición a esa API?, en esta petición se podría definir un TimeOut.

Comment: Más que TimeOut, seria como un timer porque si esa Api no responde en 10 segundos, doy la transaccion como Cancelada